# Global name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python

Alright so my guidelines are:

1. Write a program to generate 10-character strings of random lower case, upper case letters and numbers.
2. Write a program to read in random 10-character strings from (1)—(1) will be a function in part (2)—
   and characterize it as gibberish.
3. Pick ten names out of the phone book and characterize them as gibberish using your function in (2).

I am having trouble with `x` not being defined. I have added ellipses to help condense a bit. So the program is:

```
import random

import math


def randstr():
    global x
    int(x=0)
    a = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
    rs = ((random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)))
    print rs
    if rs[0] == 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
        x += 1
    if rs[0] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z':
        x += 1
    elif rs[1] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z':
        x += 1
    ...

    elif rs[9] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z':
        x += 1
    if rs[1] == 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
        x -= 2
    ...

    elif rs[9] == 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
        x -= 2
    if rs[0] == '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5' or '6' or '7' or '8' or '9' or '0':
        x -= 2
        if rs [1] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z' or 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
            x -= .25
        ...

        elif rs [9] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z' or 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
            x -= .25

    ...

        elif rs [8] == 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z' or 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
            x -= .25
    return rs

print randstr()

randstr()
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `int(x=0)` - calling a function - you have to declare it:

```
x = 0
```

Also, you don't seem to need to have the `global x` in your function.

So, here is a part of your function:

```
def randstr()
    x = 0
    #some more code
    #...
    return rs
```

And there's still a couple more problems.

First, the declaration of `rs`. What you're using is `+`, but you should use `,`, or else python will just sum all of the values, and returns a number. Remove the unnecessary brackets as well:

```
rs = [random.choice(a), random.choice(a), ...]
```

Or just use a loop:

```
rs = []
for i in range(10): #creating 10 random numbers
    rs.append(random.choice(a))
```

Your `if` statement also doesn't do what you think it does. Use the `in` operator instead:

```
if rs[0] in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
   ...
```

And similarly for other conditional statements. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you should mention how the logic in the `if` statements are not correct.

Comment: Thank you. This is a tremendous help! With the rs, I just need all 10 characters put together. We're working with distinguishing spam emails and stuff in class. Or did something go over my head?

Comment: Ah.. no, you're right then, in that case. But remove the unnecessary parentheses, it will get in your way.

Comment: Right okay. Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some other errors you need to notice before moving forward.

**First problem is in your `if` statements.**

Take a look at this example:

```
string = "foo"
if string == "foo" or "bar":
    dosomething()
```

To the human eye, that looks correct, but the computer sees it differently. When you are combining conditions with `and` or `or`, the computer checks the conditions left to right. So in this case, the computer sees:

> > If string is equal to foo or if bar

The second condition, after the `or` is the same as saying `if bar == True:` Bar is a string, and any string is *always* true, so the `dosomething()` function will *always* execute. This can be fixed by changing the above example to:

```
string = "foo"
if string == "foo" or string == "bar":
    dosomething()
```

Now the computer will execute it as:

> > If string is equal to foo or if string is equal to bar

**Simplifying your code**

The second thing I want to point out is one of the number one rules in programming: *if you're typing the same thing multiple times, there is probably a better way*

In your code, imagine replacing the already long conditions with `if rs[9] == 'A' or rs[9] == 'B'`, etc. It's going to get extremely long and messy. It would be much simpler to make a list of the alphabet, and check your variable against the list. For example:

```
alpha_list = ['A','B','C'] # etc through 'Z'
if rs[0] in alpha_list:
    dosomething()
```

The `in` keyword tells Python to check if the value of `rs[0]` is in the [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) alpha_list, or in other words, if it is a letter in the alphabet. Now you can replace all those long messy conditionals with a much shorter, cleaner solution :)

As **aIKid** pointed out, a string is also an iterable so you could replace the list with a string of all the letters (`alphabet = "ABCDEF"`...). Either one would work.

As for the original answer to your question, **aIKid** answered it perfectly, I just figured I'd try to shed some light on some other ways to help you improve!

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been curious as to how to simplify things like that! Thank you for clarification on the first part as well.

Comment: @samrap I think you can use a string straight away, since it's an iterable as well :)

Comment: Dude, you in the chat?

Comment: If you guys don't mind, I am having further issues. I have posted it as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320993/further-beginner-spam-work-in-python if you would like to help further!

Comment: Looks like you already have a few answers on there @TravisJ.Land let me know if they don't make sense to you and I'll try to clarify

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it made sense. I totally spaced on a small error when changing the program.

Answer (score 0):

So if you were to add an `x=0` or just `x=int(0)` at the beginning of your code it would work fine, because you are attempting to define `x=` as an `int()` which is not possible.

```
import random

import math

def randstr():
    # I removed the 'global x' you should not need it
    x=0             # I made the change for you
    a = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

This should fix your problem of 'x not defined' and you should also be able to get rid of the `global x`