# Further beginner spam work in python

Tags: python

I used to be able to get my string of 10 characters to contain uppercase and lowercase letters, as well as numbers. Now all I am getting is a string of lowercase characters. What did I change incorrectly?

```
import random
import math


def randstr():
    x=0
    a = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    b = ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    c = ('0123456789')
    rs = (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a))
    print rs
    if rs[0] in b:
        x += 1
    if rs[0] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[1] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[2] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[3] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[4] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[5] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[6] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[7] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[8] in a:
        x += 1
    elif rs[9] in a:
        x += 1
    if rs[1] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[2] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[3] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[4] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[5] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[6] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[7] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[8] in b:
        x -= 2
    elif rs[9] in b:
        x -= 2
    if rs[0] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[1] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[2] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[3] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[4] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[5] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[6] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[7] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[8] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            x -= .25
    elif rs[9] in c:
        x -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            x -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            x -= .25
    return rs
print randstr()
randstr()
```

Comment: You should look up how to use loops. It will greatly simplify your programs.

Comment: Please stop and refactor your code. As user1118321 mentions, using a loop would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: You need to learn about loops. There's a basic principle in programming of not repeating yourself. If you see a pattern being repeated over and over there is almost always a way to simplify it. For example, your logic could be refactored as: for letter in rs: if letter in b: x += 1;  etc...

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question why did it change, is because you are only picking from `a` in your `random.choice`.

There is a much simpler way to do this:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> random.sample(string.letters+string.digits, 10)
['e', 'l', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'T', 'K', 'H', 'B', 'w']
>>> random.sample(string.letters+string.digits, 10)
['5', 'g', 't', 'k', 'W', 'u', '4', 'T', '6', 'C']
>>> random.sample(string.letters+string.digits, 10)
['z', 'N', 'y', 'O', 'L', 'r', '6', 'D', 'V', '8']
```

Comment: While it's probably irrelevant to the OP's situation, users who are working with a non-default locale might wish to review the possible differences between `string.letters` and `string.ascii_letters`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment to `rs` only chooses values from `a`, so you won't get any upper-case letters or digits in your string.

Comment: right duh... thanks! I split it up into a b and c instead... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
...
rs = (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a))
```

Since `a` consists only of lowercase letters, so does `rs`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
rs = (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a))\
   + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a))\
   + (random.choice(a)) + (random.choice(a))
```

Is only gettting values from `a`. So it can only contain lowercase letters.